# Retrieving the data from the table in iphone

Tags: xcode, uitableview, nsmutablearray, uitextfield

I have a table wherein every row contains a textfield.After i entertext in all the rows which are text fields i want to retrieve the data into an array.Can any one tell me the idea of retrieving the data from every row which are textfields?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot believe you. Bad grammar and no research.

To get an array of all text fields, I would do:

```
NSArray *subviews = self.view.subviews;
NSMutableArray *textFelds = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


NSObject *obj;
```

for (obj in subviews) {
        if ([obj class] == [UITextField class]) {
            [textFields addObject:obj];
            CGPoint location = obj.center;
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];
            [indexPaths addObject:indexPath];
         }
    }

It first gets all of the subviews of the main view, then determines if they are text fields. If they are textFields, it adds that to an array and also gets the indexPath.

I hope I have answered your question

Answer (score 1):

You are having the details like, which row has text fields, which are not.

You can get this feature by using two different king of cells

```
    static NSString *CellIdentifierNormal = @"Cell";
    static NSString *CellIdentifierTF = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    if(indexPath.row %2 == 0){ //Example
        cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifierNormal];    
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifierNormal] autorelease];
    }
    } else {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifierTF] autorelease];    
TF *tf = [[TF alloc] init];
tf.tag = 10;
    }
```

In Text field row case, should not use the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` it re uses the existing cells, so that the text fields data may corrupt [This will happen when your data rows size greater than the table size - height]

Whenever you want collect the data from TF's

Just run loop with number of rows in table, and check same condition as you are using in creating cell.

Access the cell, and TF from cell by using tag number [10] from TF get the text